# Google Sheet Querying a Date Value from a cell in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I would like to ask if anyone knows the exact syntax to get this query working on google sheets.

I currently have 3 Sheets:

1. Sheet A, RAW DATA (where all my Raw Data is)

2. Sheet B, Main Page (where I have my user input on the date)

3. Sheet C, Filtered Data (where I would like to use the Query to pull out filtered data from Sheet A)

So I have set up a generic query goes like this in Sheet C, it works:

```
=QUERY('RAW DATA'!A:J, "SELECT * WHERE F > date '2018-03-20' AND F < date '2018-03-22' AND F IS NOT NULL ORDER BY F",1)
```

I would now like to replace the 2 dates, with user input dates, which are B5 and D5 in Sheet B.

I have tried this syntax:

```
=QUERY('RAW DATA'!A:J, "SELECT * WHERE F > date '"&Main Page!B5&"' AND F < date '"&Main Page!D5&"' AND F IS NOT NULL ORDER BY F",1)
```

Do note that B5 and D5 have already been set up with data validation rules to ensure that only date values are allowed.

Could anyone point out my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date provided to `QUERY` must be:

- a string of
- format `yyyy-mm-dd`

Try changing from

```
date '"&Main Page!D5&"'
```

to

```
date '"&TEXT(Main Page!D5,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
```

Comment: Ah! and I thought having a date validation means it will not be needed to use the TEXT function. Works brilliantly, thank you!

Comment: @TheMaster - I'm having a similar issue but with a ceiling from the same sheet. My query already has two conditions and this date condition will be the third. Current two conditions: where Col3 = '"&B1&"' and Col4 = '"&D1&"' . I thought I can add a third as such where Col3 = '"&B1&"' and Col4 = '"&D1&"' and Col1 > date '"&TEXT('"&F1&"',"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'. This returns an error. What am I missing? Date in cell F1 comes from a data validation "date" field.

Comment: @user13708028 What is the error thrown? And why are there quotes  around F1? Mine doesn't have it.

Comment: Error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "date" "date "" at line 2, column 52. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
My formula: =query(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXXXX"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 
 where Col3 = '"&B1&"' and Col4 = '"&D1&"' and date '"&TEXT(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
 order by Col5 asc",1). When formula has just the first two conditions (related to strings in another cell) it works perfectly. Adding the third (related to date) throws this error.

Comment: @user13708028 What is the third condition? Your third statement only says date. Nothing else. It should be something like Col5>date....

Comment: I think I got it. I moved the third condition, which referred to Col1, to be the first condition. It now works. Thanks, everyone!